# Bundle product dynamic pricing from options

Tags: magento-1.8, product, configurable-product, magento-1, custom-options

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I cant find a solution to this problem and bundled products might not be the answer.

Imagine a scenario where you allowed the customer to buy a customizable picture frame. The first option is the size of the frame. The available options are 10x10", 12x12", 14x14", 20x20". The next option is frame style. Which are Classic, Regular, Brushed etc...  The problem is- is their a way to change the price dynamically depending on a previous option? For Example:

- Option 1: 10x10" + Option 2: Brush = $100.00,
- Option 1: 12x12" + Option 2:Brush = $120.00,
- Option 1: 14x14" + Option 2: Brush = $140.00

... and so on.

A. Can customizing / changing the bundle products be a solution? or...

B. Do you have to tackle this issue another way with Magento?

Any links to blogs posts or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1: Configurable products

I'm not sure what's the reason to use bundle products over configurable products here.

Here's what I would do.

I would **create a configurable product based on the two following product attributes**:

- size of the frame
- frame style

You will obviously have to add the options to the attribute before starting.

- Create your configurable product
- Set the price of the configurable product as the minimum possible price ($100 ?)
- Now, after save and continue edit, go to the associated products tab

Here's the critical part to achieve what you want, for each combinations you'll have to:

- in the quick simple product creation fill the weight, status, qty and visibility
- then choose the combination for the two configurable attributes (e.g. 10x10" + brush, 12x12" + brush etc...)
- click the quick create button
- Now you said that the price increases only based on the first attribute (size of the frame), you'll have to add the extra cost in the super product attributes configuration section:
- e.g. for 10x10'' fixed price = 0, for 12x12'' fixed price = 20, for 14x14'' fixed price = 40 etc...

This way, whenever a customer chooses the size of the frame, the price will be updated on the fly based on the extra cost you provided.

### Option 2: Custom options

Another way of doing it in case you don't want simple products for each combination would be to use custom options.

- Create a simple product
- Set the price as the minimum possible price
- Go to the custom options tab and click the Add new Option button
- In the Title write "Size of the frame", select dropdown in the input type and set the sort order to 1
- Now click add new row for each size available
- Foreach size fill the title with the size, price as the extra cost (0 for 10x10'', 20 for 12x12'' etc...), the sku and the sort order.
- Now click the Add new Option button again
- In the Title write "Frame style", select dropdown in the input type and set the sort order to 2
- Now click add new row for each style available
- Foreach style fill the title with the size, price as the extra cost (should always be 0 as the price seems to only be based on the size), the sku and the sort order.

Comment: can you elaborate on this line:
e.g. for 10x10'' fixed price = 0, for 12x12'' fixed price = 20, for 14x14'' fixed price = 40 etc...

Comment: @Nige in the price field where you add the extra cost you have a dropdown, you need to choose fixed price and then enter the extra cost so 0 for 10x10'', 10 for 12x12'' etc...